# make install fails for openni-drivers

Tags: openni, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I use Ubuntu 11.04 and I try to communicate to a Kinect sensor (the kinect
is not connected). I followed the instruction  from http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect and  get some problems.
In 1. Install the Openni drivers onto your system

*hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers
cd drivers
make
make install*

after make install  I have got :

sd@sd:~/drivers$ make install
cd openni && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sd/drivers/openni'
cd build/openni/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist && bash RedistMaker && cd -

---

- PrimeSense OpenNI Redist    *
- ```
  2012-05-25 00:26:32       *
  ```

---

Target: Linux-x86
Version: 1.5.2.23
Num of compile jobs: 4

- Building OpenNI...
  ../../../../../Source/Utils/niLicense/niLicense.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  ../../../../../Source/Utils/niLicense/niLicense.cpp:122:108: warning: format ‘%lu’ expects type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int’
  ../../../../../Source/Utils/niLicense/niLicense.cpp:129:97: warning: format ‘%lu’ expects type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int’
- Creating Doxygen...
  warning: ignoring unsupported tag `INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES =' at line 295, file Doxyfile warning: ignoring unsupported tag` INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  =' at line 304, file Doxyfile
  warning: ignoring unsupported tag `CITE_BIB_FILES         =' at line 579, file Doxyfile warning: ignoring unsupported tag` HTML_EXTRA_FILES       =' at line 926, file Doxyfile
  warning: ignoring unsupported tag `MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     =' at line 1202, file Doxyfile warning: ignoring unsupported tag` LATEX_FOOTER           =' at line 1282, file Doxyfile
  warning: ignoring unsupported tag `LATEX_BIB_STYLE        =' at line 1321, file Doxyfile warning: ignoring unsupported tag` INTERACTIVE_SVG        =' at line 1734, file Doxyfile
  sh: C:\Program Files\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe: not found
  error: failed to run html help compiler on index.hhp
- Creating Redist Dir...
- Copying files to redist dir...
  Samples: ['SimpleViewer.java', 'NiSampleModule', 'NiUserSelection', 'SimpleRead.java', 'NiSimpleViewer', 'UserTracker.java', 'NiSimpleRead', 'NiConvertXToONI', 'NiRecordSynthetic', 'NiBackRecorder', 'NiUserTracker', 'NiAudioSample', 'NiHandTracker', 'NiViewer', 'NiSimpleCreate', 'NiSimpleSkeleton', 'NiCRead']
- Removing Read Only Attributes...
- Fixing Files...
- Creating Makefile...
- Copying install script...
- Building Samples in release configuration......
- Building Samples in debug configuration......
- Creating tar......
- Redist OpenNi Ended.   !!
  /home/sd/drivers/openni
  touch installed
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sd/drivers/openni' sudo mkdir -p /usr/include/openni \ /etc/openni \ /usr/share/openni/doc \ /usr/share/openni/samples \ /usr/lib/pkgconfig sudo cp -f ./openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-xx-v1.5.2.23/Samples/Config/* /etc/openni/ cp: cannot stat` ./openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-xx-v1.5.2.23/Samples/Config/*': No such file or directory
  make: *** [install_openni] Error 1

Well have you any idea what the problem is?
I need your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34796/make-install-fails-for-openni-drivers/) by [sd1973ds](https://answers.ros.org/users/2456/sd1973ds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does installing the binary package (`apt-get install ros-fuerte-openni-kinect`) work?

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1